# How can I view the mapping between GPOs and registry settings?

Tags: windows, active-directory

As far as I know, GPOs function as a high-level view of registry settings, i.e., setting a GPO directly corresponds to setting some registry keys and/or values.

I would like to know exactly what registry settings a certain GPO changes. Is there some tool that can tell me that, or would I need to look it up on MSDN (provided such documentation exist)?

Comment: Are these GPO's part of the Administrative templates provided with the OS or customised GPO's created/added/imported by an admin? yagmoth555's link would help if they are Administrative templates included with the OS. If you are creating customised policies and want to see which registry settings then you could use SysInternal's Process Monitor to monitor registry settings changes on a system, create/edit group policy, apply change and then see what settings were changed via Process Monitor.

Comment: Note that not all group policy is implemented via registry settings.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - can you give an example?

Comment: Drive mappings is probably the simplest example.  But only the Administrative templates are *directly* and *explicitly* implemented as registry settings, i.e., that's how the group policy client works for Administrative templates, it just applies the registry settings provided in the relevant template.  For everything else the group policy client is running some code, e.g., if you use group policy to grant a privilege to a group, the group policy client calls LsaAddAccountRights or an equivalent function.

Comment: ... of course, the GP client may well use the registry internally in deciding what settings are new and which have already been handled, and a function like LsaAddAccountRights might be manipulating policy information that is stored in the registry, but those are internal implementation details and there isn't necessarily a 1:1 correspondence between a GP setting of this sort and the registry changes that it causes.

Answer (score 4):

There is an Excel soreadsheet that list the GPO versus the registry key location.

Please see it there; https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250

Comment: Good document, but describes only Windows settings. For MS Office, for example, somewhere there was a separate table.

Answer (score 3):

Modern GPO templates are stored in the system in the `admx` format - in fact, this is `xml`, which can be opened with any text editor.

It's stored at `c:\windows\policydefinitions`.

You can easily open template and peek at which registry branch the policy setting is saved.

The only thing is: if you will search for setting by name, you first need to find string id in coresponding `adml` (stored near in locale specific folder), and look in `admx` for this string id instead of real setting name.